# How to preserve the order of the output of the command when piping to fzf

Tags: bash, fzf

I have bash function that allows me to copy a line from history.
Here's the function

```bash
history_cp() {
  history | 
    sort --reverse --numeric-sort | 
    fzf | 
    awk '{ $1=""; print }' | 
    tr -s ' ' | 
    xclip -selection clipboard 
}
```

It works fine, but `fzf` doesn't maintain the order of the results, how do i keep the sorted results?

Comment: I've noticed that `fzf` sorts differently based upon different types of whitespace - ie. what may look like a space on screen, that isn't a space but is actually a tab (and visa versa, etc) is sorted accordingly. In which case try using `fzf --no-sort` to prevent `fzf` sorting the results coming from your `sort --reverse --numeric-sort` output.

Comment: awesome, it seems to do the trick so far.